# Unable to display uploaded image in production

Tags: nginx, file-upload, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have added file upload to a Phoenix app, and am able to display the uploaded image in development and also in production locally when starting the app in the console.

My specific problem is that when I upload an image to the production server, the files are uploaded and copied to the correct directory, but I can't access them from the browser.

The Static plugs in my Endpoint are as follows:

```
plug Plug.Static,
  at: "/", from: :bookingmot, gzip: false,
  only: ~w(css fonts images js html favicon.ico robots.txt)

plug Plug.Static, at: "/uploads", from: Upload.base_path, gzip: false
```

The Upload module handles any tasks required for the upload, and base_path is defined as follows:

```
def base_path do
  System.get_env("UPLOAD_PATH")
end
```

The Env var UPLOAD_PATH is defined on the server as:

```
/home/[username]/www/phoenix/[app-name]/uploads

# to clarify, the contents of [app-name] are the results of
# tar xfz app-release.tar when deploying
```

All uploaded files are copied to the above directory fine, but if I then enter the following in the browser I just get Page not found returned.

```
http://[app-url]/uploads/[name-of-file-in-uploads-folder]
```

The development VM and the production server are both Centos 7, and the production app is sat behind Nginx.

I think that's everything but I'm happy to supply more info if it helps.

Comment: Can you confirm `Upload.base_path` actually returns the path you expect when you're calling it? Try adding `IO.inspect(Upload.base_path)` before `plug Plug.Static, at: "/uploads", from: Upload.base_path, gzip: false` and checking the output in the production server. Note that that line will be executed when the app is being _compiled_, not when it's being run.

Comment: Hi, yes it does, already inspected that. Upload.base_path is also used for the path when copying the file from the tmp folder after upload (to ensure both the read and write paths are the same), and the file is copied to the correct location. I also printed the path in the view where the image is supposed to display, and it points to the correct directory.

Comment: Apologies to Dogbert, even in italics, I missed the importance of the use of the word _compiled_, sorry. Your comment would have lead me in the right direction had I read it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I experienced similar problem.

How my first approach looked like:

```
#lib/endpoint.ex
plug Plug.Static,
  at: "/uploads",
  from: Application.get_env(:app_name, :full_upload_path),
  gzip: false

#config/config.exs
config :app_name,
  full_upload_path: Path.expand("./uploads")
```

We are using two separate servers for compilation and as deploy target. It wasn't working because during compilation path was expanded to `/home/builds/app_name/uploads` instead of the expected `/home/user/app_name/uploads`.

How we fixed it:

```
#config/production.exs
config :app_name,
  full_upload_path: "/home/user/app_name/uploads"
```

Now it's using hardcoded path in production and expanded path elsewhere

TLDR: try to set UPLOAD_PATH variable on machine on which you compile your release

Comment: That solved it. I was still thinking in Ruby terms that the config vars would be read at run time. Now I'm thinking a better solution might be to set my Vagrant VM up exactly the same as my production server rather than using the normal vagrant user in development.